# Can play embedded video from different platform in videoview?

Tags: android, youtube, vimeo, embedded-video, dailymotion-api

I think my problem is describe well in title but I give you some details:

I develop app associated with a backoffice where customers can publish news, gallery and other stuff included link to video such as youtube, dailymotion, vimeo, etc...

I have already use a library : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3

But as you might expect i can only play youtube video, so I search method, library, parser; that could work with many platform included youtube, dailymotion, vimeo.

I hope you can help me, Thanks you in advance.

Comment: I also test this parser: https://github.com/yixia/VParser but without good result ;)

Answer (score 0):

Every provider wil have their own way to enable you to embed videos and interact with them.

For adding Dailymotion videos into your application, you should use the dailymotion APIs and the SDK. You will find all documentation you need in the developper website http://developer.dailymotion.com

There is an android SDK that will be useful for you: http://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#sdk-android

Depending on your usage, you may also find some services aggregating the use of different providers (for example, if you only want to embed videos, you have services such as http://api.embed.ly/ )